# Inconsistent behaviour of svn info

Tags: svn

Due to a complex structure in a SVN repository, some external files are not correctly retrieved from the repository.  As changing the repository structure is not an option, I have developed a script that iterates through the externals and retrieves them 'by hand' if needed (thanks to 'svn export').  To detect if this operation is indeed needed, I execute 'svn info', assuming that it will return different from 0 if the file does not exist, or it is not versioned.  That was indeed the behavior obtained in host1 (SVN Client 1.6.17):

```
# Initially, the directory is empty
host1$ ls
host1$ svn update

Fetching external item into 'main.rbf'
svn: warning: '<REMOTE_SVN_LOCATION1>'
is not the same repository as
'<REMOTE_SVN_LOCATION2>'

At revision 18413.

# Although we do the update, the external item is not fetched,
# as it is a single file coming from a different repository
# (known problem)
host1$ ls
# The file is not present, and SVN info acts accordingly
host1$ svn info main.rbf
main.rbf:  (Not a versioned resource)

svn: A problem occurred; see other errors for details

# If we force the SVN export
host1$ svn export <REMOTE_SVN_LOCATION1> main.rbf
A    main.rbf
Export complete.
host1$ ls
main.rbf

# then SVN info detects it and acts accordingly
host1$ svn info main.rbf
main.rbf:  (Not a versioned resource)

svn: A problem occurred; see other errors for details
host1$
```

In host2, (SVN Client 1.6.11), the behaviour of 'SVN info' is completely different: no matter if the file is there (from a previous export) or not, the answer is:

```
# Directory is empty
host2$ ls
host2$ svn info
Path: .
URL: <REMOTE_LOCATION>
Repository Root: ...
Repository UUID: ...
Revision: 18413
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: ...
Last Changed Rev: 18326
Last Changed Date: ...

host2$
```

Is there any reason to explain this inconsistent behavior? How can I detect this unversioned file in host2 ?